# Start/Stop an event on specific time in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In Android I want to start an event on a specific time and stop it as well. e.g. phone should go on silent mode at 12:00 am and return to normal mode at 8:00 am. I've gone through other questions but they are about triggering an event only, not stopping one. Please write a step by step procedure for achieving this task.

Comment: please show us what you have done so far. Usually, if you started the alarm via AlarmManager, you can stop it just by using the same PendingIntent and call `mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);`

Comment: No one is going to write a complete code here, you need to start by your own. Google it, how to raise alarm, canceling alarm, setting audio profile etc..

Answer (score -1):

you can try GCMNetworkManager or jobscheduler or Alarm

Comment: I am not trying to do some network related tasks. I just want to save some information at put the phone on silent and at specific time phone should go back to normal mode and change the saved information.

Comment: this is not a relevant answer, can be added as a comment.

Comment: You can try JobScheduler or Alarm. Do you check GCMNetworkManager

Comment: GcmNetworkManager mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this); long setTimeOff = calcTimeAsReq(System.currentTimeMillis())
                // Schedule oneoff task.
                OneoffTask oneoffTask = new OneoffTask.Builder()
                        .setService(MyCustomClass.class)
                        .setTag(taskItem.getId())
                        .setExecutionWindow(0, setTimeOff)
                        .setExtras(bundle)
                        .build();
                mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(oneoffTask);